# How to check two values in array mysql using codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I'm new to codeigniter. I having a problem checking two values in field using a model with codeigniter.

I'm trying to check if "status" value is "Available" or "Notavailable"

I'm using this model to check but only one value. 'Available' Only.

```
public function withdraw_check($data)
{
    $this->db->select('game');
    $where = array('id_user' => $this->session->userdata('user_id'),
                   'status' => 'Available', 
                   'game' => $data,
                   'site' => $this->system_library->sitename()
                  );
    $this->db->where($where);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use a WHERE IN statement:

```
$this->db->where_in('status',array('Available','Notavailable'));
```

SQL Produced:

```
WHERE status IN ('Available', 'Notavailable')
```

Final Code:

```
$this->db->select('game');
$this->db->where('id_user',$this->session->userdata('user_id'));
$this->db->where_in('status',array('Available','Notavailable'));
$this->db->where('game',$data);
$this->db->where('site', $this->system_library->sitename());
```

Comment: I'll try that @Jeemusu tnx

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
 $this->db->select('game');
 $where = array
                (
                    'id_user' => $this->session->userdata('user_u_id'),
                    'game' => $data,
                    'site' => $this->system_library->sitename()
                );
$this->db->where('status=' ,'Pending');
$this->db->or_where('status=' ,'Hold');
$this->db->where($where);
```

Comment: ` ''Pending' ` something wrong here. Double quotes coming there. Verify it again.